# Activity Icon Disabled in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

In Android Studio 1.1.0, I have the HOLO Theme selected as my App theme.
For some reason the Logo is not appearing on the activity bar in my app. But it is showing on my XML Layout.
I have tried enabling it from the Manifest by `android:logo="@drawable/title_icon"` and from the the code by

`actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
 actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);`

Nothing seems to work.
The point is it is showing in my XML Layout, but when I load the app on my android, it jus doesnt show up.

Comment: `actionBar.setLogo`?

Comment: @karaokyo Well tried it jus now with  `actionbar.setLogo(R.drawable.title_icon); `
no luck.
Is this an issue with my theme?

Comment: Well, if you are building with v21, the support library will be using material theme, which does not have the icon by default. If you want to use Holo, you can switch your `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and change your theme to holo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you also need `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionbar.setLogo(R.drawable.title_icon);
```

Comment: it worked finally! thanks!
so that line made the difference afterall!